# sqlite3_prepare_v2 returns null for statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite

Running my code via Visual Studio Launcher, prepare_v2 function returns null for statement (but the error code is SQLITE_OK). However launching from the exe via Windows Explorer works as intended.

Since it works from the executable i assume db-,table- and column names are correct. Therefore its (imo) not a virtually created database (which may occur if db-name is empty (or wrong?)).

The database and sqlite-dll are copied to the output directory (prebuild event).

So i assume its something VS2013 intern?

Comment: Stop using relative paths and the issue will go away.

Comment: omg, apparently 4am isnt the right time. totally forgot that the lauch path is bind to the project directory when launching via visual studio.

Comment: @IInspectable want to ellaborate as answer, so i can accept it?

Comment: If the database were empty, you wouldn't get SQLITE_OK.

Answer (score 1):

The only situation where `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` returns no statement but `SQLITE_OK` is when the statement text is empty.

Apparently, your code does not construct any SQL statement at all when the current directory is not the project directory.